# Express: Share session with websocket

Tags: node.js, express, session, websocket

I'm writing a chat application with node.js and Express. The authentication is working and I can login to user accounts and register new sessions. My problem is that the chat itself runs within a Websocket (Websocket-node) and I can't access the session data. How can I identify new connection requests made to the websocket without the session data?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would advise not working with WebSockets directly and instead use Socket.IO.  It has authorization and handshaking built in

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Here is how you can get session information

http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Since I'm quite far with the implementation already and since I don't have to worry about backwards compatibility I'd like to stick with websocket-node. My idea now is to read the cookie information which is send in the connection request and check the session database for the equivalent userId. I can print the cookie (request.cookies), something like: `[ { name: 'connect.sid',
    value: '7bWPjMtfQHTxoCZI2yFLLEVN.mByzCs9Wx5FOmg' } ]`, but I don't know how to access the value of connect.sid properly.